# Get the time between consecutive dates stored in a single column

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to figure out how to get the time between consecutive events when events are stored as a column of dates in a dataframe.

```
sampledf=structure(list(cust = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), date = structure(c(9862, 
9879, 10075, 10207), class = "Date")), .Names = c("cust", "date"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can get an answer with

```
as.numeric(rev(rev(difftime(c(sampledf$date[-1],0),sampledf$date))[-1]))
# [1]  17 196 132
```

but it is really ugly.  Among other things, I only know how to exclude the first item in a vector, but not the last so I have to rev() twice to drop the last value.

Is there a better way?

By the way, I will use ddply to do this to a larger set of data for each cust id, so the solution would need to work with ddply.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(sampledf, 
              c("cust"), 
              summarize,
              daysBetween = as.numeric(rev(rev(difftime(c(date[-1],0),date))[-1]))
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
as.numeric(diff(sampledf$date))
# [1]  17 196 132
```

To remove the last element, use `head`:

```
head(as.numeric(diff(sampledf$date)), -1)
# [1]  17 196

require(plyr)
ddply(sampledf, .(cust), summarise, daysBetween = as.numeric(diff(date)))

#   cust daysBetween
# 1    1          17
# 2    1         196
# 3    1         132
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `diff`.

```
as.numeric(diff(sampledf$date))
```

To leave off the last, element, you can do:

```
[-length(vec)] #where `vec` is your vector
```

In this case I don't think you need to leave anything off though, because `diff` is already one element shorter:

```
test <- ddply(sampledf, 
      c("cust"), 
      summarize,
      daysBetween = as.numeric(diff(sampledf$date)
))
test
#  cust daysBetween
#1    1          17
#2    1         196
#3    1         132
```