# Calulcate running difference of time using difftime on one column of timestamps

Tags: r, difftime

How would you calculate time difference of two consecutive rows of timestamps in minutes and add the result to a new column.

I have tried this:

```
data$hours <- as.numeric(floor(difftime(timestamps(data), (timestamps(data)[1]), units="mins")))
```

But only get difference from time zero and onwards.

Added example data with 'mins' column that I want to be added

```
timestamps                        mins
2013-06-23 00:00:00               NA
2013-06-23 01:00:00               60
2013-06-23 02:00:00               60
2013-06-23 04:00:00              120
```

Comment: I would suggest that you post some sample data to make your example reproducible. Your code alludes to making use of the `difftime` which I would use when calculating the difference. Jumping across pairs of values would be a matter of indexing. You could then do whatever desired with the results. Also have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213228/get-the-time-between-consecutive-dates-stored-in-a-single-column) which touches on a similar issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code that you're using with the [1] is always referencing the first element of the timestamps vector.

To do what you want, you want to look at all but the first element minus all but the last element.

```
mytimes <- data.frame(timestamps=c("2013-06-23 00:00:00",
                                   "2013-06-23 01:00:00",
                                   "2013-06-23 02:00:00",
                                   "2013-06-23 04:00:00"),
                      mins=NA)
mytimes$mins <- c(NA, difftime(mytimes$timestamps[-1],
                               mytimes$timestamps[-nrow(mytimes)],
                               units="mins"))
```

What this code does is:

1. Setup a data frame so that you will keep the length of the `timestamps` and `mins` the same.
2. Within that data frame, put the timestamps you have and the fact that you don't have any mins yet (i.e. `NA`).
3. Select all but the first element of timestamps `mytimes$timestamps[-1]`
4. Select all but the last element of timestamps `mytimes$timestamps[-nrow(mytimes)]`
5. Subtract them `difftime` (since they're well-formatted, you don't first have to make them POSIXct objects) with the units of minutes. `units="mins"`
6. Put an NA in front because you have one fewer difference than you have rows `c(NA, ...)`
7. Drop all of that back into the original data frame's mins column `mytimes$mins <-`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to calculate it with this approach:

```
# create some data for an MWE
hrs <- c(0,1,2,4)

df <- data.frame(timestamps = as.POSIXct(paste("2015-12-17", 
                                            paste(hrs, "00", "00", sep = ":"))))

df
# timestamps
# 1 2015-12-17 00:00:00
# 2 2015-12-17 01:00:00
# 3 2015-12-17 02:00:00
# 4 2015-12-17 04:00:00

# create a function that calculates the lag for n periods
lag <- function(x, n) c(rep(NA, n), x[1:(length(x) - n)])

# create a new column named mins
df$mins <- as.numeric(df$timestamps - lag(df$timestamps, 1)) / 60

df
# timestamps mins
# 1 2015-12-17 00:00:00   NA
# 2 2015-12-17 01:00:00   60
# 3 2015-12-17 02:00:00   60
# 4 2015-12-17 04:00:00  120
```

Comment: Thanks you all. Again. Many roads leads to Rome :-)

Comment: Simple and easy! Solved my issue :) Thanks David.