# How do I calculate the duration for multiple continuous occurrence of an event?

Tags: r, data.table

This is a subset of my data

```
    # | Event | Time
    1    A       22:00:00
    2    B       22:00:10
    3    B       22:00:20
    4    B       22:00:30
    5    C       22:00:40
    6    B       22:00:10
    7    B       22:00:20
    8    B       22:00:30
    9    A       22:00:40
```

I want to calculate the duration of a continuous occurrence of a same event – so, say I want the duration of event B, the output should be

```
    # | Event | Time      | Duration
    1    A       22:00:00   NA
    2    B       22:00:10   20 Secs
    3    B       22:00:20   NA
    4    B       22:00:30   NA
    5    C       22:00:40   NA
    6    B       22:00:10   20 Secs
    7    B       22:00:20   NA
    8    B       22:00:30   NA
    9    A       22:00:40   NA
```

I've tried (variations of) solutions from: 
[Using conditional statements with difftime in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819415/using-conditional-statements-with-difftime-in-r)  and
[Calulcate running difference of time using difftime on one column of timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333685/calulcate-running-difference-of-time-using-difftime-on-one-column-of-timestamps)

But I can't seem to get what I'm trying to achieve. Hope I can get some help! Thanks!

Comment: Try `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(Event)][, Time := chron::times(Time)][Event == "B", Duration := c(as.numeric(max(Time)-min(Time))*24*60*60, rep(NA, .N-1)), grp]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), create a grouping variable based on the run-length-id of 'Event' i.e. based on same adjacent elements ('grp'), convert the 'Time' to `POSIXct` , grouped by 'grp', specifying the 'i' with the logical condition (`Event == "B"`), find the difference of the last and first 'Time1' using `difftime`, then we assign the values of the 'Duration' that is not the first observation for each 'grp' to NA.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(Event)][, Time1 := as.POSIXct(Time, format = 
       "%H:%M:%S")][Event == "B", 
     Duration := as.numeric(difftime(Time1[.N], Time1[1], unit = "secs")), grp]
df1[df1[, .I[seq_len(.N) != 1], grp]$V1, Duration := NA][, c("Time1", "grp") := NULL][]
#   No Event     Time Duration
#1:  1     A 22:00:00       NA
#2:  2     B 22:00:10       20
#3:  3     B 22:00:20       NA
#4:  4     B 22:00:30       NA
#5:  5     C 22:00:40       NA
#6:  6     B 22:00:10       20
#7:  7     B 22:00:20       NA
#8:  8     B 22:00:30       NA
#9:  9     A 22:00:40       NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(No = 1:9, Event = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", 
 "B", "B", "A"), Time = c("22:00:00", "22:00:10", "22:00:20", 
 "22:00:30", "22:00:40", "22:00:10", "22:00:20", "22:00:30", "22:00:40"
 )), .Names = c("No", "Event", "Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Woah it works! Do you think you could explain the steps? I'm pretty new to r and the use of data.table

Comment: @cookiedookie Thanks, I updated with some description